# Console output cannot link to the source files (remote build using synchronized project)

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse CDT's "Synchronized C/C++ Project" for building on remote machine. I do the coding on local machine and always compile and run on remote. The synchronization works fine and so does the compilation.

However, output printed in console is of the remote build including files and paths. So I cannot click on any error to navigate it in my code. I have to check the file containing error and manually navigate to it on local machine. Is there any way to link remote code path to local so that output in console (error messages) are clickable like usual C++ project?

Thanks